# Is it possible to autocomplete user's text input in telegram?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

If there is a command-like text in the telegram chat room, it becomes clickable. (Please refer to below picture.)

Is there a way to make it so that if someone clicks on the telegram command-like text such as `\set_something`, the text of the command itself gets automatically entered into the user's input window where they type rather than the command itself being sent to the chatroom?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sort of custom behaviour can be achieved only if you write a custom Telegram client.

You cannot do that using [Telegram bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) alone.